# Font Awesome CSS checkbox with empty label

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am trying to get CSS only radio and checkbox buttons using FontAwesome. I have a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/d0do7sff/).

I am using the following CSS which works well, when the checkbox has a label with content. i am now trying to just create a matrix of checkboxes in a table on my page and the icons appear OK but cannot be clicked  / changed state.

My CSS:

```
/**
 * Checkboxes
 */


input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}


/* to hide the checkbox itself */

input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  content: "\f0c8";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
}


/* unchecked icon */

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  content: "\f14a";
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}


/**
 * Radio buttons
 */

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}


/* to hide the radio itself */

input[type=radio] + label:before {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  content: "\f111";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
}


/* unchecked icon */

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
  content: "\f192";
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label:hover,
input[type=radio] + label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div>
  <i class="fas fa-square"></i> SAMPLE UNCHECKED
  <br/>
  <i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> SAMPLE CHECKED
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input name="access_chk[]" class="access_chk" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="access_chk[]"></label>
  <br/>
  <input name="access_chk[]" class="access_chk" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="access_chk[]"></label>
  <br/>
  <input name="access_chk[]" class="access_chk" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="access_chk[]"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The icons cannot be clicked, because you are not clicking the checkbox, just the pseudo element before. The only walk around, to style checkboxes, is to mimic the events with js

Comment: Hi @Julien Ambos the checkboxes / radios are not working using FA. See fiddle.

Comment: Hi @Andrei Gheorghiu I am using each checkbox to trigger a on the fly AJAX update on back end. So I do not need the values. But I have added values to JSFiddle and still the same.

Comment: @MarceloOrigoni are you sure about that? http://jsfiddle.net/d0do7sff/19/

Comment: I'm arguing this is not a dupe of the flagged question. The flagged question is regarding padding/spacing. This question is regarding actual functionality. The solutions are quite different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:
Since your labels are empty anyway, why use them at all (unless you have some hidden screenreader-properties, you don't need empty labels...ever).

The trick is to use the pseudo-elements on the checkboxes themselves instead of the labels. To make the checkboxes work, use `visbility:hidden` on them and `visibility:visible` on the pseudo-elements.

Minor drawback: You'll have to fiddle around with font-size a bit, otherwide the glyphs might appear too small.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility:hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]::before {
  visibility: visible;
  font-size:16px;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  content: "\f0c8";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked::before {
  content: "\f14a";
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
</div>
```

Comment: Even better solution. Many thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't say my solution is better. It might fit your particular case better. But Jon P points out something very important about how to use labels and his solution is equally valid.

Comment: Happy for yours to be the accepted answer. Mine points out the fundamental issue. Yours provides a more streamlined solution.

Comment: Its not a good practice to use pseudo-elements `:before`, `:after` on input elements. It works only on chrome, `firefox` does not support it. Check your answer in `firefox` you will see the difference. [**Read this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field)

Comment: Damn, you're right. @TheRealPapa I suggest, you accept the other answer again, mine is flawed.

Comment: Thought I'd checked this in FF, apparently not. Good catch @BhuwanBhatt

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `for` attribute applies to the `id` attribute of the target element **not** the `name` attribute.

Change your markup to:

```
<div>
  <i class="fas fa-square"></i> SAMPLE UNCHECKED
  <br/>
  <i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> SAMPLE CHECKED
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input name="access_chk[]" value="1" class="access_chk" type="checkbox" id="cb1" checked>
  <label for="cb1">LABEL WITH CONTENT</label>
  <br/>
  <input name="access_chk[]" value="2" class="access_chk" type="checkbox" id="cb2" checked>
  <label for="cb2"></label>
  <br/>
  <input name="access_chk[]" value="3" class="access_chk" type="checkbox" id="cb3" >
  <label for="cb3"></label>
  <br/>
  <input name="access_chk[]" value="4" class="access_chk" type="checkbox" id="cb4" checked>
  <label  for="cb4"></label>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d0do7sff/19/)

Comment: YOU ROCK! Thanks!